# Use VBA to open URL in Default-Browser an catch existing Session

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, redirect

I try to open a specific URL of a web-application I'm already logged in (or tells me to login if I'm not) in the default browser (Chrome). When I copy/paste this URL into the browser address bar, it perfectly works. It doesn't when I open this URL by VBA with `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink` - then it redirects - as a kind of fallback - to the homepage instead the specific URL.

I found out that this is a session problem and VBA somehow doesn't recognize/catch the existing session.

As "ugly workaround" I'm currently redirecting over http://www.dereferer.org/ to the specific URL, what perfectly works, but is needing additional time.

This doesn't work:

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("https://www.example.com/function/edit/2019-04-09)
```

This works:

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("http://www.dereferer.org/?https://www.example.com/function/edit/2019-04-09)
```

*(for my needs it's not required to encode the target URL)*

As this redirect is slow and indirect, I'm searching for a way to directly open the targeted URL **while using the existing session** (if possible). If this isn't possible (for example because of security), what's the best/fastest way to redirect without setting up an own redirector (which redirects like dereferer.org over a GET parameter)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A clunky and ill-advised workaround, but you *could* bypass `FollowHyperlink`, and instead use `Shell` to open the website in a new tab/window of  your default web-browser:

```
Shell "explorer ""https://www.example.com/function/edit/2019-04-09"""
```

(As a note, if you type as a hyperlink in a cell and clicked on it manually, instead of using VBA `FollowHyperlink`, then the same issue would still occur.  This also happens in Word and PowerPoint.  Just be thankful you're not trying to catch the `FollowHyperlink` *event* and "correct" that in the window)

In response to comments - for Mac you will need to use `"open"` instead of `"explorer"`.  This code should run on both Mac or PC:

```
Shell IIf(Left(Application.Operatingsystem, 3)="Win","explorer ","open ") & _
    """https://www.example.com/function/edit/2019-04-09"""
```

Comment: I'll test your solution in the evening. Thanks also for the remark related the hyperlink. For my current target it should work, as I've mapped the Sub/Macro to a button. One additional question: Do you know if this works also for Excel on Mac's? (I don't have one and can't test it but want to stay as compatible as possible).

Comment: @Andy I believe that you would need to change `"explorer ""https://www.example.com/function/edit/2019-04-09"""` to `"open ""https://www.example.com/function/edit/2019-04-09"""` for Mac

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly and is super fast (I didn't test the mac version, but according what I found on the net it should too) exactly as I've aimed. Sometimes the solution can be so easy WHEN you know it finally...

Comment: @Chronocidal How would you use the `Shell` *version* of this to ensure that when you click on a link in a cell, it opens using that, just as when you use `FollowHyperlink`? I have posted a question of a related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73122968/1147688).

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to install selenium basic I would use that

```
Option Explicit

'download selenium https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0
'Ensure latest applicable driver e.g. ChromeDriver.exe in Selenium folder
'VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to selenium type library
Public Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "url"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        'login steps
        .get 'otherUrl'
        Stop '<delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this creative answer - funnily I just looked into the Selenium VBA approach. But for my specific case it would be an overkill, as I really just need to open a specific URL and don't want to create dependencies if it's not critically needed.